# Console.log() de un objeto me devuelve undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

sucede que estoy usando el método find() para buscar un único documento y guardar el documento en la constante info, posteriormente y aquí viene mi problema es que quiero extraer un campo de data en una nueva constante y utilizar esa constante para buscar de nuevo obtengo un valor undefined, tengo esto para que entiendan mejor:

```
movimientosCtrl.getInfo = async (req, res) => {
        const info = await infoSchema.find()
        console.log(info)
        const codigo = info.Codf
        console.log(codigo)
        const info_dos = await movimientosExtremos.find({Codf: codigo});
        res.json(info_dos)
}
```

El primer console (console.log(info)) me retorna:

```
[ { _id: 5f016ddfaa6b4338106923bb, Codf: '8021799407124', __v: 0 } ]
```

pero el segundo (console.log(codigo)) me retorna undefined por lo tanto mi segunda búsqueda no puede ser manejada y responde un array vacío.

Por favor, si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal que me lo haga saber xd y gracias.

Comment: ¿ocurre lo mismo si declaras las variables con `let`?

Comment: El problema es que `info` es un `Array`. Para acceder a sus elementos debes iterar sobre sus índices, por ejemplo: `console.log(info[0].Codf);` te dará el primer elemento. Siempre es bueno verificar que el `Array` si contiene elementos. Puedes usar la propiedad `length` para este propósito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `info` es un [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array).

Para acceder a sus elementos debes iterar sobre sus índices, por ejemplo:

```
console.log(info[0].Codf);
```

te dará el valor del primer elemento.

Siempre es bueno verificar que el `Array` contenga elementos antes de intentar iterarlo. Puedes usar la propiedad [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/length) para este propósito.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const arr = [];

const arr2 = [{k: 'valor1'}];

if(arr.length) {
  console.log(`Tamaño arr: ${arr.length}`);
  arr.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.k);
  });
}

if(arr2.length) {
  console.log(`Tamaño arr2: ${arr2.length}`);
  arr2.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.k);
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En el código anterior, se verifica el tamaño del `Array` antes de intentar acceder a sus elementos.

Tu código podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
movimientosCtrl.getInfo = async (req, res) => {
  const info = await infoSchema.find(); // el método find() siempre devuelve un array (Mongoose - MongoDB)
  console.log(info);
  if(info.length) {
    const codigo = info[0].Codf; // <- Devuelvo el primer elemento.
    console.log(codigo);
    const info_dos = await movimientosExtremos.find({Codf: codigo});
    res.json(info_dos);
  }
}
```

Si deseas que devuelva un sólo elemento, deberías usar el método [`findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne), el cual efectivamente te devuelve un único documento y así tu código no tendría el problema que presenta ahora.

Por ejemplo:

```js
movimientosCtrl.getInfo = async (req, res) => {
  const info = await infoSchema.findOne(); // <- findOne devuelve el primer documento encontrado
  console.log(info);
  // si existe al menos 1 documento en BD, será devuelto
  // cabe la posibilidad que no exista ninguno,
  // en ese caso info.Codf será undefined;
  const codigo = info.Codf;
  console.log(codigo);
  const info_dos = await movimientosExtremos.find({Codf: codigo});
  res.json(info_dos);
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias, eso era. tengo problemas con los arrays y objetos (Y)